# Raspberry Pi and Tomcat -> pi4j unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, maven, jersey, tomcat7, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi (type B) that runs a java web application on Tomcat7. I am using the  "Jersey" java framework in collaboration with Pi4J, to control the GPIO on the Pi.The ultimate purpose is to control a relay switch, but I won't go into that.

When I try to access the web service, it throws a tomcat error (shown below):

[image: tomcat error shown in browser]

I have used the build tool Maven to create the web application, making it dead easy to import the libraries. Can anybody notice anything I'm doing wrong with my simple code to make the gpio "blink" below? I can confirm my jersey setup is correct because it works when Pi4J isn't involved.

**Web Service class** (ignore the name XMLService for now)

```
@Path("")
public class XMLService {

    GPIORelay gpio = new GPIORelay();

    @Path("/blinktest")
    @GET  
    public String blinkTest(){
         try{
             gpio.blink();
             return "successful";
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            return "failed";   
         }

    }
```

**GPIORelay class**

```
public class GPIORelay {
    GpioController gpio;
    GpioPinDigitalOutput pin;
    String currentStatus;

    public GPIORelay(){
        gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        pin = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_00, "Pin 17", PinState.LOW);

    }

    public void blink(){
        try{
            pin.high();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pin.low();
            gpio.unprovisionPin(pin);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.print("Exception ");
        }
    }
}
```

Doing some initial reading, it could be because I need to install the pi4J libraries on the Raspberry pi itself in addition or maybe I need to configure the java.library.path but I still find it unclear. Any help from somebody that has worked with Pi4J before would be great!

Thanks.